# How to input two element

Tags: haskell

This is my code on Haskell

```
module Q5Degrees where

-- The relationship between temperature c in degrees Celsius and temperature f in degrees Q5Degrees
-- is defined by the function
--   c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9
-- Data types to represent temperature values in Q5Degrees and Celsius
data Fahrenheit =
  F Double
  deriving (Show)

data Celsius =
  C Double
  deriving (Show)

-- | convert
-- Takes a value representing temperature in degrees Fahrenheit and converts   it to degrees Celsius
--
-- Examples:
--
-- >>> convert (F 50)
-- C 10.0
-- >>> convert (F 14)
-- C (-10.0)
convert :: Double -> Double
convert f = (f - 32) * 5 / 9

-- | equals
-- Takes values representing temperature in degrees Celsius and degrees Fahrenheit and returns True
-- if they are equal (to within 0.5 degrees Fahrenheit), and False otherwise
--
-- Examples:
--
-- >>> equals (F 34) (C 1)
-- True
-- >>> equals (F 33) (C 0)
-- False
-- >>> equals (F 32) (C 0)
-- True
equals :: Double -> Double -> Bool
equals ("F" y) ("C" x)
 | (y-32)*5/9 == x = True
 | (y-32)*5/9 /= x = False
 | otherwise = False
```

The doctest requires to input two value (F 34) (C 1). Can anyone teach me how to fix this line  in order to pass the doctest. I have tried to put 
    equals x y 
There is an error if I input (F 34) (C 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to make the code compile, you need two things here:

```
equals :: Fahrenheit -> Celsius -> Bool
equals (F y) (C x)
 | (y-32)*5/9 == x = True
 | (y-32)*5/9 /= x = False
 | otherwise = False
```

1. Don't put the constructor names in quotes (quotes are only for strings)
2. The argument types need to be `Fahrenheit` and `Celsius`, not `Double` and `Double`.

To fix the failing doctest on `convert`, you also need to change its types so they aren't `Double`.

```
convert :: Fahrenheit -> Celsius
convert (F f) = C ((f - 32) * 5 / 9)
```

The `equals` doctest is failing. First let's simplify your code.

```
equals :: Fahrenheit -> Celsius -> Bool
equals (F y) (C x) = (y - 32) * 5 / 9 == x
```

I'm not sure what to do about this doctest, because the test itself looks wrong. 34 degrees F is not equal to 1 degree C; it should be 10/9 C. But you're not going to get working equality tests here because you're using `Double`, and so you're going to get floating point rounding error. Maybe you want to change your representations from `Double` to [`Rational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Rational)?

Comment: Or more simply, `equals y x = convert y == x` if `Celcius` derives `Eq`.